# Doubly transitive and solvable

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, solvable-groups

I wonder if there are subgroup of $S_n$ that are solvable and doubly transitive for $n\geq 5$.
Can someone find an example or prove that they don't exist?

Comment: Yes there are lots of examples, like ${\rm AGL}(1,q)$. Why don't you try googling "solvable doubly transitive group"?

Comment: Ah, great. Thank you!